# List users who have an empty description field in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filtering

I'm trying to get a list of Active Directory users who have no description set.

I start with getting a list of users:

```
$users = Get-AdUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq "True" )} -Properties Description
```

And then I tried these options (to get list of users with no description):

```
$NoDescrUsers = $users | Where-Object {$_.Description -eq ""}
$NoDescrUsers = $users | Where-Object {$_.Description -eq ''}
$NoDescrUsers = $users | Where-Object $_.Description -eq ""
$NoDescrUsers = $users | Where-Object {$_.Description -match ""}
$NoDescrUsers = $users | Where-Object -not {$_.Description -like '*'}
```

None of these work (or it returns 0 in a `foreach` or returns everyone). What should my command look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why none of the options you tried worked (it seems like they should). Having Googled the general consensus seems to be that you can do this successfully (and more efficiently) within the initial `-filter`. For example:

```
$NoDescrUsers = Get-AdUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq "True" ) -and (description -notlike '*')} -Properties Description
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your method works perfectly. I also am still not sure why the methods I had find didn't seem to work.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you filter *description -like or -notlike*

> '*'

) that means you'll take any character (or not).

If you want filter only empty description in your AD request, you could do:

```
$NoDescrUsers = Get-AdUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq "True" )  -Properties Description

if ($NoDescrUsers.Description  -eq  $null)

{write-host "no description"}
```